# Php mongo client count query not working Mongo 4 version

Tags: php, r, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I have upgrade MongoDB version 4 from 3. the below query is not working in the php mongo client.

```
db.transaction_history.count(array("transaction_type" => "post_create", 'nid' => 111111),array('nid' => 1))
```

the above query was working in the older version

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Hello, do you have an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with the new php mongo driver v 1.5+ (supporting MongoDB v4)

```php
$mongoClient->myCollection->count($search, $options);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.count.php